# Flash Develop warning : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My code is :   when i write tweenline flashdevelop closes . moreover it showed many times "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex" this warning .

```
package  
{

     import com.greensock.layout.AlignMode;
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.events.MouseEvent;
     import flash.net.URLLoader;
     import flash.net.URLRequest;
     import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
     import flash.net.navigateToURL;
     import flash.display.DisplayObject;
     import com.greensock.TweenLite;
     import com.greensock.easing.Circ;

     public class Main extends MovieClip 
     {

           public var BgMC:MovieClip;
           public var logoMC:MovieClip;

           public var bannerWidthArray:Array  = [550];
           public var bannerHeightArray:Array  = [400];
           public var loopcount:Number=0;
           public var loop:Number=2;

           public function Main() :void  
           {
                if (stage) init (); 
                else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE , init); 
           }

           private function init (e:Event=null):void  
           {
               removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
               startbanner ();
           }

           private function startbanner (): void 
           {
               BgMC = new bg_mc();
               logoMC = new logo_mc();
               BgMC.x = 0;
               BgMC.y = 0;
               addChild(BgMC);

               logoMC.x = 20;
               logoMC.y = 10;
               addChild(logoMC);
               initAnimation (); 
           }

           private function initAnimation () : void 
           {
               BgMC.alpha = 10;
               logoMC.alpha = 10;
               // ? Weird
               Tweenlite(         
           }

     }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but how is anyone supposed to help you with this if you basically tell us nothing? We are not magicians. Judging from that error I can tell you one thing: the index is out of range somewhere. Also: Why the Java tag?

Comment: People are going to flag this if you don't provide any of your code.

Comment: I bet startIndex was either negative, or greater than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the first version of your question, I understand that your are speaking about a FlashDevelop .Net error and not a ActionScript one, so try to find a solution in the [FlashDevelop forum](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/).

Answer (score 0):

yes. i have found the exact answer for you . it happed for me . Because Everybody thinks that his/her windows is Program Files (x64) but that's not . you are running C:\Program Files (x86) . that's why you need to install another Jdk.

just go to jdk download website and you will see that they have different jdk for Program Files (x86) . http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Download it what exactly you are running in C:\Program Files (x86) .and your many kinds of problem related like this is solved